Firebase / Send notifications : Is there any migration guide from legacy API to HTTP v1 API for PHP server scripts (not hosting)?
I'm quite desperated trying to get my PHP server script running with HTTP v1 since Google stopped the functionality of Lecagy in June. No message has been send successfully anymore.
I'm using a webspace with php and I'm not the provider, so I can't install third party packages or set environment variables, but that is always needed in all examples I've found so far.
My old code was running with code lines like this (not complete):
$curl = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $FCM);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

but I do not find a suitable replacement for this for HTTP v1. I know that there's a new URL for init
$curl = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/....../messages:send");

but that will not be enough to be substituted. Is there ANY suitable example for users who are  not hosting their PHP environment by themselves ? Any help / hint would be highly appreciated ...

You can install 3rd-party packages via your local dev environment (you've got one of those, right??), and then upload the resulting codebase to your hosted environment once you've tested and verified that it's working. You don't need to have composer or whatever in your hosting (I assume this is what the problem is, although you weren't 100% clear about it).

And environment variables are totally optional - if you don't want to use them, don't - just substitute their usage from the examples with however else you want to store those values (e.g. hard-coded, from a DB, or text file, whatever). Any competent programmer should be able to adapt an example solution to their own needs and swap out any components which don't suit them - especially when those components are peripheral to the core purpose of the example. It shouldn't really be necessary to create 100 different examples to suit everyone's exact setup. Use what you need, replace what you don't

Hello @ADyson thanks for your quick reply. Is there any step-by-step-tutorial to realize your hints ? I do not really know what you mean with your steps ...

Which examples have you been looking at already? It would help if you send us a link to an existing tutorial that you wanted to use. Like I said: It shouldn't really be necessary to create 100 different examples to suit everyone's exact setup. What bit of what I said are you stuck with exactly? e.g. If you have a problem using environment variables, then don't use environment variables - instead of loading the needed data through an environment variable, just change the code so it loads it by another method instead. I don't  really know how else to explain that?

I'm looking at this :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
Update authorization of send requests : Before / After :
What code is to be implemented in PHP environment ?
Provide credentials manually : I generated the json file , but after that ?
No idea at all. What will I have to code to get it working in PHP like before with the curl_setopt / curl_exec lines ?

You have to obtain an access token using the method described, depending on which authentication flow you need to use in your app - either using ADC or getting the credentials manually. It sounds like manually is the method you'd need, if you're not running this PHP code in google's cloud. So you have to create a service account as described (if you don't already have one) and download the JSON credentials file. Then load the contents of that file into your PHP app (you can specify the path any way you like, doesn't need to be an environment var) ...

... then use the Google Auth Library (the PHP one is here, as per the links from the documentation: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php) to obtain the access token, and lastly put the access token into the header of your cURL request.

When I read this, I immediately stuck on the part "Installing via Composer".
Where do I do this ? How will it move to server side ? The requirements are not obvious
I use VS code for client side and Filezilla for FTP transport to server. Will it be neccessary to embed my php files in a local server using XAMPP with PHP?

you wrote there's no need to use composer ... but what is the alternative way to do like they wrote on github site ?

Unfortunately it's not very, helpful for me to be told the process. I need the path to the goal, a php code sbippet

you wrote there's no need to use composer...that's not quite what I said - please re-read my comment. I said you don't need to have composer installed in your hosting environment. Instead, use composer in your _local development environment _ i.e. on your own machine, where you are (hopefully) developing and testing your code before you upload it to your server. If you install all the libraries locally, you can then just copy the whole codebase, including the installed libraries, to your hosted server when you deploy the code.

(Of course in theory you don't need composer at all - its job is just to simplify the process of adding 3rd-party libraries, and their dependencies, to your application. You could install all those libraries manually into your application - it's a case of copying the right files to the right place, and ensuring you've got all the files you need, and writing require statements to add them to your app. But of course it would be a lot more time-consuming and error-prone to do it that way...which is why almost everyone these days uses composer if they want to install other libraries.

Unfortunately it's not very, helpful for me to be told the process...ok, but also what research have you done already? What's wrong with the answers in posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782134/how-to-use-the-fcm-http-v1-api-with-php ? Surely that would get you started, at the very least? (To find this I simply typed "firebase HTTP v1 api PHP" into google and looked at the first few links...)

I retried your search and the first 7 results where highlighted because I've been there before ... However ... Thanks for your efforts

Well then, what's wrong with any of those results? You've said you don't want to use environment variables, so I explained what the alternatives are. You've said you can't use composer in your hosting environment, so I've told you how to work round that. You've said you don't understand how to get the access token from google, so I've found you an example which shows how to do that using PHP.  So, given all of that, where are you stuck still? Like I said, you should be able to make a start on your task now.

When I call the link for google-auth I read :
Install Composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
Next, run the Composer command to install the latest stable version:
composer.phar require google/auth
I installed local windows version of Composer . It automatically updated my system path. so far, so good ... And then ? WHERE do I run the composer command "composer.phar require google/auth" ? WHERE ? In VS Code in my terminal ? doesn't work ...   In a cmd shell ?   Doesn't work ...

Please tell me WHERE I have to execute that statement to install  the latest version

when I execute it in cmd shell , windows asks me to select which program to be used to open that file ...

I'm not familiar with namespaces, so where do I place the github code in my environment to succeed ?

I downloaded the zip of the google auth code and unpacked it.
Can anybody please tell me where to place it in my environment and please tell me the code line in php to obtain  the Access Token ? I'm quite confused

Don't download the zip file, use composer to install the library into your PHP project. If you use the zip file you have to install all the dependencies etc by hand, which will add a lot of complexity

WHERE do I run the composer command "composer.phar require google/auth"...from the folder of your PHP project where you want to add this dependency. You may need to write the full path of the composer executable, if it's not in the PATH for your command shell (the same as for any executable you try to use in a windows command-line shell)

If you haven't used Composer before I strongly suggest following Composer's own tutorials (https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md and then https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md). Do that on a separate PHP project you've created to practice on. Do that so you can get used to how composer works, how it installs things, where to run the command from, and so on. That way you're less likely to have problems or make mistakes when you come to use it on your real project.

tell me the code line in php to obtain the Access Token...I already linked you to an example, remember? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871906/5947043 . It's not one single command. Please study the provided resources fully, and try it out, before asking again.

Before you roll your eyes, please see my tries to come to an end :
I put the dowbloaded sources of the Google Service in root dir of my local project. I did not change the name of the folder.
I created a new empty php file in root named auth.php. first line is: require_once './google-auth-library-php-main/autoload.php';

I called authphp file via local environment. he found the autoloader, no error. When he entered function getOATHToken to instantiate Google_Client,
he correctly entered autoloader function oauth2client_php_autoload($className). He analyses the parameter 'Google_Client' and calculated
a path to a php file to require named '...my-project\auth\google-auth-library-php-main/src/Google/Client.php'. But that file does not exist
in the context of the downloaded google class files.  There is not even a class named Client defined in any file of the sources. So that's where I
stuck.

And there isn't any idea what to do now. Are there any namespacing annotations to fix ? Is a file missing ?
Every example uses this way of implementing, no additional hints. But it seems that I forgot something

This is why we use Composer, instead of trying to install the library manually. Your life will be easier if you take a bit of time to learn it.

You will NOT believe it, but ... I finally did it ! Everything is nothing without composer. I got everything installed correctly and even every notification sent ... Thanks a lot for your patience !!

Well done, glad you got it sorted out
